# Problem with Extracting NSString from TXT

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsstring, text-files

I am trying to create one long string from a text file. This is the code that I currently have. I do not really understand the encoding and I tried to research but found nothing. This is the line of code that I have:

```
NSString* data = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"12thnew.txt" encoding: error:NULL];
```

When I entered the encoding as NSASCIIStringEncoding, and asked to print the string in NSLog I got the null error. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` means that your text file only contains characters within the 0-127 range (8 bit chars).  You can read up on that here: [NSString docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSASCIIStringEncoding).  You most likely will want to use UTF-8, no?  The value to use is: `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

The file has to have some encoding. You can't create an NSString without one. In most cases, `NSUTF8StringEncoding` will be the right choice. It handles ASCII correctly as well as UTF-8. You can tell Cocoa to guess for itself by using `initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`.